# How to test is a passed object is a collection or an array

Tags: java

I have a logger class and here is one of its methods:

```
public static void i(String tag, Object message) {
    if (message != null) {
        i(tag, message.toString());
    } else {
        i(tag, ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY);
    }
}
```

this `message!=null` check is not sufficient for `List`, `Map`, `Set` or `array`, in the case when they are not null but they are empty. So how do I test if the passed object is something that has a `size` or a `length` so that I show the `ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY` message?

Comment: `instanceof Collection<?>` ?

Comment: are arrays Collection<?> as well?

Comment: You can easily check that :) Give it a try.

Comment: Calling `toString()` on an array isn't going to give you a useful output to start with...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Class.isArray()`:

```
public static boolean isArray(Object obj)
{
    return obj!=null && obj.getClass().isArray();
}
```

Also works for arrays with primitive types.

And you can use `Class.isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)` to check whether object is an instance of `Collection`:

```
public static boolean hasSize(Object obj)
{
     return obj!=null && Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid the test completely by overloading the method and providing an `Iterable` version.

```
// Shouldn't really use raw types here.
public static void i(String tag, Iterable messages) {
    if (messages != null) {
        /* 
        Probably need a bit more than this 
        as String.join takes an `Iterable<? extends CharSequence>
        but that is not an insurmountable problem.
        */
        i(tag, "["+String.join(",", messages)+"]");
    } else {
        i(tag, ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY);
    }
}

public static void i(String tag, Object message) {
    if (message != null) {
        i(tag, message.toString());
    } else {
        i(tag, ERROR_PARAMETER_IS_NULL_OR_EMPTY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your broader question:

```
static boolean isEmptyArray(Object o) {
  if (o == null || !o.getClass().isArray()) {
    return false;
  }
  if (o instanceof int[]) {
    return ((int[])o).length == 0;
  } else if (o instanceof long[]) {
    return ((long[])o).length == 0;
  } else if (o instanceof double[]) {
    return ((double[])o).length == 0;
  } else if (o instanceof byte[]) {
    return ((byte[])o).length == 0;
  } else if (o instanceof char[]) {
    return ((char[])o).length == 0;
  } else if (o instanceof boolean[]) {
    return ((boolean[])o).length == 0;
  } else if (o instanceof float[]) {
    return ((float[])o).length == 0;
  } else if (o instanceof short[]) {
    return ((short[])o).length == 0;
  } else { // it is an array, so it can only be an object array now.
    return ((Object[])o).length == 0;
  }
}
static boolean isEmptyCollection(Object o) {
  return (o instanceof Collection) && ((Collection)o).isEmpty();
}
```